# Mono.Cecil How to define an output parameter

Tags: .net, il, mono.cecil

I want to add a new method via Mono.Cecil which has an output parameter, like:

```
private static bool XXXXX(out Int32 a)
```

I tried the following codes to add this parameter

```
TypeReference typeInt32 = targetAssembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Int32.Resolve();
typeInt32 = targetAssembly.MainModule.Import(typeInt32);
method.Parameters.Add(new ParameterDefinition(typeInt32) { Name = "a", IsOut = true });
```

And I compare the IL codes between the one I added and the one complier generates. they are different.

**Mine added by Cecil:**

```
.method private hidebysig static bool XXXXX([out] int32 a) cil managed
```

**Compiler generates:**

```
.method private hidebysig static bool XXXXX([out] int32& a) cil managed
```

Please anyone knows how to make my Cecil added method the same as the complier generates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the type has to be by reference: `int32&` (or `ref int` in C# syntax)

```
ByReferenceType typeInt32ByRef = new ByReferenceType(typeInt32);
method.Parameters.Add(
    new ParameterDefinition(typeInt32ByRef) { Name = "a", IsOut = true });
```